# Launching lib/main.dart on Windows in debug mode... Unable to build: could not find vcvars64.bat

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

i am trying this tutorial https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-desktop-create-and-run-a-desktop-application-ebeb1604f1e0
and when i run `flutter run` it showing this error ,how to solve

> Launching lib/main.dart on Windows in debug mode... Unable to build:
>   could not find vcvars64.bat

Answer (score 1):

[Desktop Embedding for Flutter](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding) suggests following as set up tools required.
Make sure you have :

1. [Visual Studio 2017 or 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), including the **"Desktop development with C++"** *workload.*
2. Your Project should be in the same directory as the flutter

         ├─ flutter (from https://github.com/flutter/flutter)
         └─ Your Project

Comment: FYI, the second bullet point is unrelated to the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get that problem:

- If you haven't installed the necessary platform development tools, as another answer said. The [project the instructions in that post are based on](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding) includes those requirements, but the author of the post didn't include them for some reason.
- If you installed Visual Studio in a non-default location (see [this bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33249)). In that case, you need to add the directory containing `vcvars64.bat` to your path.